# Ошибка: NoMethodError at / undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток.
Достался не рабочий продукт. Не знаю как заставить работать из-за малого опыта работы с `ruby-on-rails`.
При загрузке выдает ошибку

> NoMethodError at / undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

в строчке

```
<td class="grid-cell-choose td_center"><input name="sub[]" type="checkbox"<%=' checked="checked"' if @aliases.include?(sub[:subscriptionId]) %> value="<%=sub[:subscriptionId]%>">
```

в логе пишется

```
  DEBUG -- : HTTP request status='getAllSubs' service=''
ERROR -- : HTTP error. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
```

у меня подозрение что просто необходимо в ошибочной строчке дописать `else` для `if`'а в котором `include`.
Так ли это?
Посоветуйте как побороть проблему.

Comment: sub[] очень странное название для html элемента, особенно когда оно используется в erb. Использую интроспекцию в руби проверьте объекты которые в передаете в вид. Как видите один из них @aliases равен nil, поэтому при рендере шаблона возникает ошибка

Comment: у вас `@aliases` равно `nil` потому и ошибка, а заполнить его надо в контроллере/

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте проверку что @aliases не нул например так:

```
if @aliases and @aliases.include?(sub[:subscriptionId])
```

Хотя Вам наверное надо ещё разобраться, почему он null.